# HTC One V rooted - can't upgrade from htc release

Tags: updates, htc-one-v

I have an htc one v and there's a system update from htc.
I'm trying to do the update, it needs to restart in order to finish the update.
When it restarts clockworkmod jumps in and the update never finishes.
I was trying to a zip update through clockworkmod but it does not work.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to flash official update from manufacturer on rooted phone:
1) Look for flashable zip with untouched or just rooted official ROM with latest updates included.
2) Revert your ROM and Bootloader to manufacturers default and then install update

You can find stock roms and instructions to revert to stock in [XDA Developers Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1554)